`shmget` Invalid argument error -- is memory still allocated from a previous execution?
I have the following program to exercise using forks and shared memory.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>

int main() {
    int bignum = 1000000;
    
    key_t key = ftok(".", 'x');
    int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(int)*bignum, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (shmid < 0) {
        perror("shmget\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int *arr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    pid_t c1 = fork();
    if (c1==0) {
        pid_t c2 = fork();
        if (c2==0) {
            pid_t c3 = fork();
            if (c3==0) {
                arr[0] = 10;
            } else {
                arr[1] = 11;
            }
            wait(NULL);
            exit(0);
        } else {
            arr[2] = 12;
        }
        wait(NULL);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        arr[3] = 13;
        wait(NULL);

        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }


    shmdt(arr);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    exit(0);
}

I previously ran this program using a smaller amount of shared memory and have now increased it to see if that affects the program in any way. When I run this I get:
shmget
: Invalid argument

I've seen this post: C linux shmget Invalid argument
I've tried following the advice, but I'm unfamiliar with ipcs and ipcrm.  I ran ipcs in a terminal and it gave me some shared memory info.  But I can't tell which is the one allocated by the program, there's a lot, and I can't tell what is safe to remove or not.
It also seems odd to me that you wouldn't just do this inside the C program itself, so that makes me wonder if there isn't a better way to resolve this issue. I particularly don't get why the calls to shmdt and shmctl don't make this a non-issue.  Is there some other way to "undo" memory sharing?

Edit: The question was closed because it is similar to this:
C - System V - remove shared memory segment
However, that uses code that is already in my code -- so it doesn't seem to answer the question.

Edit: Here is my updated code based on an answer.  It does resolve the previous issue, but now after some error checking, raises a permission error.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>

int main() {
    size_t bignum = 1000000*sizeof(int);
    
    key_t key = ftok(".", 'x');
    int shmid = shmget(key, bignum, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (shmid == -1) {
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
        shmid = shmget(key, bignum, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
        if (shmid == -1) {
            perror("shmget");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    int *arr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if (arr == (int *)-1) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }

    shmdt(arr);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    shmid = shmget(key, bignum, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    arr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    pid_t c1 = fork();
    if (c1==0) {
        pid_t c2 = fork();
        if (c2==0) {
            pid_t c3 = fork();
            if (c3==0) {
                arr[0] = 10;
            } else {
                arr[1] = 11;
            }
            wait(NULL);
            exit(0);
        } else {
            arr[2] = 12;
        }
        wait(NULL);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        arr[3] = 13;
        wait(NULL);

        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    if (shmdt(arr) == -1) {
        perror("shmdt");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("shmctl");
        exit(1);
    }

    exit(0);
}

Specifically, when I run this it results in
shmget: Permission denied


You could print out the value of the key within your program.

I recommend that you exit your old program by following the answer in the duplicate. That is, do shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL); before the original parent exits. Your new program should then not have a problem creating a new shared memory with the same id. You should probably add shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL); to this new version too to not have this allocation in your system forever :-)

@NateEldredge I just now tried but still get the same error.

@TedLyngmo Unless I'm misunderstanding, it seems to me that my current program already calls exactly that function before the parent exits.  The exit is the last line of main and right before it this is called.  But again, perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.

Is it possible that some previous version of your program didn't destroy the segment, or crashed before doing so?

@NateEldredge That is very likely -- I think I only added the cleanup after running it a couple times without it and then realized I needed to add it.  Still I'm confused as to why, when I print the key and then order it to clean and then make a new key, I seem to continue getting this error.

@Addem: Yes, of course printing the key won't fix the error by itself, but it would allow you to identify which of the segments shown in the ipcs output is the one from your program, and then you could ipcrm it.

@Addem It's your old program that needs to call it. Run the program using the old allocation. Exit by removing the shared memory. Then, run the new program and all will be fine. Or, start the new program by removing the old memory chunk first.

ftok() performs a determinate computation (it must, in order to serve its purpose).  Thus, you can get the wanted shmid by running the same ftok() call in another program.  And as long as you're doing that, you can make that program perform the wanted shmctl call with IPC_RMID, too.

@NateEldredge Well yes, like I said I printed it and then used it to clean, i.e. called shmctl(<the key that it printed>, ...).

Note that since you are not intending to share this segment with any processes except your own descendants, you could avoid ftok entirely and just use IPC_PRIVATE.  Then there would never be a conflict with other instances of this program - past, present, or future.

shmctl takes a shmid, not a key.  You would have to shmget the segment using the key to get the shmid, then destroy it.  If you check the return value of shmctl you should see that it failed.

@NateEldredge Ah great, that worked! I used IPC_PRIVATE and it resolved all issues.  One day I might want to understand how the other stuff works, but I'll let that come up if and when needed. (Edit: Just saw your explanation, that now makes sense. Thank you again!)

Also, if you just want a block of memory to share with your descendants, a simpler way is mmap with MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED.  (If you need POSIX compatibility beyond Linux then open and map /dev/zero instead of using MAP_ANONYMOUS.)

General note for any further responses: I intend to look into mmap in the future.  This was all just an exercise to become familiar with shm, so that I can at least understand what other people are doing when they use it, and stuff like that.  So rather than switching to mmap I wanted to just suffer through the pain of working with shm until I at least kind of get it.  :)

The old program left a smaller shared memory segment lingering after it exited so attaching to it, requesting a bigger size, fails. You can start your new program by removing it:
key_t key = ftok(".", 'x');
int shmid = shmget(key, 1, 0666); // no IPC_CREAT

if (shmid != -1) { // ok, there was a memory segment there already
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL); // remove it
}
// now create the new one
shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(int)*bignum, IPC_CREAT | 0666);


Ah this makes sense now.  I'm not sure I quite understood what you meant by old and new programs and so on, but I think I get this now.  And it indeed fixes the problem, so thank you!

@Addem Glad it helped! You're welcome!

Ooh, I may need to correct myself: This does seem to fix something.  But now when I check the size of arr which results from this, it still says the size is 8 (the old value for four ints).  And when I try to print the element of index 10, I get a segfault, so it seems like this has not actually allotted extra shared memory.

(Also, I've tried further steps to clean up the old memory by making the key, making an array, detaching the array, and shmctl the key, then building it all back up.  But still the shared memory does not take on the new multiple of bignum.)

@Addem No problem! don't know how you check the size, but I suspect it's incorrect.  The failure to allocate memory should be solved with my answer, but I'd need a [mre] for the new situation.

I just had the idea of throwing error checking around and found that apparently this is actually caused by a permission error from shmat.  If I can't figure out how to resolve that, I'll update the post with the new code and let you know -- although you sound confident, so maybe the question is indeed resolved at this point.  :)

Well, I tried searching for similar issues and couldn't find any.  I am sure you're right that your code worked as expected and this new error is somewhat unrelated.  But I updated the post to include the new code anyway, in case you think it is related, or in case you had any thoughts about what's causing it.

Well, I may have obviated the issue.  I finally figured out how to eliminate the shared memory from the terminal, and now it seems to work.

shmget doesn't attach the memory segment to the process virtual memory.  For that you need a properly created shared memory identifier (this is what you get with shmget) and then call using the value returned as parameter to indicate the kernel which memory segment you want to attach.
The memory is actually allocated by shmat system call.  But if you weren't able to get the id, then you will not be able to attach it to your memory space.
    int shmid = shmget(key, bignum, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (shmid == -1) {
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

If you got an error above, then there's no reason to call shmctl because the id is invalid.
        shmid = shmget(key, bignum, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

IMHO, if you failed the first call, you will fail it again.  Did you get a different result the second time?  shmctl has not solved the problem because you don't have a valid shared memory identifier, so the kernel doesn't know which memory segment are you referring to (indeed, it does not exist)  You need to check the parameters you pass t the shmget syscall.  Does the shared memory already exist?  Is the key you pass (this is, have you already run the program and created a memory segment with the same key?) a valid key?
        if (shmid == -1) {
            perror("shmget");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

invalid parameter normally indicates that a problem with a parameter value is present.  I'm afraid that you have specified IPC_CREAT and the memory segment already exists.  A good idea should be to print the numbers the kernel gives to you as you get them.  This will allow you to know where your program is failing (when numbers start to appear unexpected, that's a symptom that the previous syscall has failed for some reason)
A common mistake when using sysV calls for IPC is that the kernel maintains the resources as long as the system is running.  If you forget to delete the resources you created, then they will be there until you reboot the system.  The first time you use IPC_CREAT probably you succeeded, but failed later in the shmat syscall... this means that the segment already exists.
The Berkeley system call mmap has a simpler interface and is more flexible, requiring only one system call to create and attach the memory space you want to share (that memory can also be backuped in a file, allowing you to access a file contents by mapping the file to the virtual memory address space)  I don't know if you can use mmap in your system, but I suggest you to, at least have a look at it.
